flutter how to enable build cache?
My app suddenly requires about half of an hour to build, which is significantly slow. I noticed that the terminal outputs
  Build cache is disabled

So I am guessing that if I enable the build it might be faster?

But I don't know how to enable it or any means to make the build faster.
Can anyone please help?

To enable it go to gradle.propreties and put this line

org.gradle.caching=true

like that you can build more faster
